# The favicon is gone on SO in the review queue and on the users page

Tags: bug, internet-explorer, favicon

As soon as I enter a Review Queue from the Review page the favicon doesn't get served the first time. On the Answer tab on my user page the fav-icon disappears after hitting the sort buttons for the second time.

[image: favicon gone]

After hitting F5 or going to the Questions or Tags pages does show a favicon. I can only repro this on IE10, on Chrome it doesn't repro, nor on FireFox

Exact repro steps in IE10:

1. Hit your profile page
2. click the Answers tab
3. click the Votes sort button
4. click the Activity sort button

notice fav-icon is gone.

click on the Answers tab again to have the fav-icon of SO back.

The fav-icon gets reverted to the default after the second time an XMLHttpRequest is done on the current page.

This now only occurs on the Review queue in IE11 (check dec, 17th)

Notice that this also occurs on the Users page on MSE when clicking on Activity tab and then on the Al tab.

Comment: Confirmed in IE9 as well.

Comment: Why isn't your top bar gray?

Comment: [Actually, I rely on the disappearing favicon to alert me to a new review task.](http://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: @rene Actually, [here's something better](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34659592/so-red.ico).